# Counting Consecutive Duplicates For By Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset with an id column, date column and value.  I would like to count the consecutive appearances/duplicate values of id for a continuous date range.

My question is very much like [Count consecutive duplicate values by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793736/count-consecutive-duplicate-values-by-group) but in Python.
Moreover, the question is different from [How to find duplicates in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825521/how-to-find-duplicates-in-pandas-dataframe) because I need the count to be based on two columns where one is not identical - it is the date (which changes, but if it's consecutive I want to count it)

Here is a sample dataset:

```
ID      tDate            value
79  2019-06-21 00:00:00  397
79  2019-07-13 00:00:00  404
79  2019-07-18 00:00:00  405
79  2019-07-19 00:00:00  406
79  2019-08-02 00:00:00  410
79  2019-08-09 00:00:00  413
```

I would like to resultant dataset to be:

```
ID      tDate            val  consec_count
79  2019-06-21 00:00:00  397  0
79  2019-07-13 00:00:00  404  0
79  2019-07-18 00:00:00  405  1
79  2019-07-19 00:00:00  406  2
79  2019-08-02 00:00:00  410  0
79  2019-08-09 00:00:00  413  0
```

I marked the "singles" with 0 and not 1 because I need to tell the two apart.  I will deal with batches of 'duplicates' differently than single records.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try to create mask on groupby of `ID` and `or` it with `shift(-1)` to flag all consecutive rows `True` and assign to mask `s1`. Finally, use `np.where` on `s1` and  `s1.groupby.cumsum`

```
s = df.groupby('ID').tDate.diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
s1 = s | s.shift(-1, fill_value=False)
df['consec_count'] = np.where(s1, s1.groupby(df.ID).cumsum(), 0)

Out[185]:
   ID      tDate  value  consec_count
0  79 2019-06-21    397             0
1  79 2019-07-13    404             0
2  79 2019-07-18    405             1
3  79 2019-07-19    406             2
4  79 2019-08-02    410             0
5  79 2019-08-09    413             0
```

Answer (score 5):

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80], 
                   'tDate': [pd.Timestamp('2019-07-12 00:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-13 00:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-18 00:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-19 00:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-20 00:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-08-03 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-06-21 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-06-22 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-18 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-19 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-26 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-08-02 00:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-08-03 00:00:00')],
                   'value':[397, 404, 405, 406, 408, 413, 397, 404, 405, 406, 408, 410, 413]})

print (df)
    ID      tDate  value
0   79 2019-07-12    397
1   79 2019-07-13    404
2   79 2019-07-18    405
3   79 2019-07-19    406
4   79 2019-07-20    408
5   79 2019-08-03    413
6   80 2019-06-21    397
7   80 2019-06-22    404
8   80 2019-07-18    405
9   80 2019-07-19    406
10  80 2019-07-26    408
11  80 2019-08-02    410
12  80 2019-08-03    413
```

**Solution**:

```
a = df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
s = (~a).cumsum()
df['consec_count']=np.where(a.groupby(s).transform('any'), df.groupby(s).cumcount(1).add(1),0)

print (df)
    ID      tDate  value  consec_count
0   79 2019-07-12    397             1
1   79 2019-07-13    404             2
2   79 2019-07-18    405             1
3   79 2019-07-19    406             2
4   79 2019-07-20    408             3
5   79 2019-08-03    413             0
6   80 2019-06-21    397             1
7   80 2019-06-22    404             2
8   80 2019-07-18    405             1
9   80 2019-07-19    406             2
10  80 2019-07-26    408             0
11  80 2019-08-02    410             1
12  80 2019-08-03    413             2
```

**Explanation**:

First create mask for compare difference per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with one day:

```
print (df.assign(diff= df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff(),
                 a = df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))))
    ID      tDate  value    diff      a
0   79 2019-07-12    397     NaT  False
1   79 2019-07-13    404  1 days   True
2   79 2019-07-18    405  5 days  False
3   79 2019-07-19    406  1 days   True
4   79 2019-07-20    408  1 days   True
5   79 2019-08-03    413 14 days  False
6   80 2019-06-21    397     NaT  False
7   80 2019-06-22    404  1 days   True
8   80 2019-07-18    405 26 days  False
9   80 2019-07-19    406  1 days   True
10  80 2019-07-26    408  7 days  False
11  80 2019-08-02    410  7 days  False
12  80 2019-08-03    413  1 days   True
```

Create unique groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with inverted condition by `~`:

```
print (df.assign(diff= df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff(),
                 a = df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')),
                 a_neg = ~a,
                 s = (~a).cumsum()))

    ID      tDate  value    diff      a  a_neg  s
0   79 2019-07-12    397     NaT  False   True  1
1   79 2019-07-13    404  1 days   True  False  1
2   79 2019-07-18    405  5 days  False   True  2
3   79 2019-07-19    406  1 days   True  False  2
4   79 2019-07-20    408  1 days   True  False  2
5   79 2019-08-03    413 14 days  False   True  3
6   80 2019-06-21    397     NaT  False   True  4
7   80 2019-06-22    404  1 days   True  False  4
8   80 2019-07-18    405 26 days  False   True  5
9   80 2019-07-19    406  1 days   True  False  5
10  80 2019-07-26    408  7 days  False   True  6
11  80 2019-08-02    410  7 days  False   True  7
12  80 2019-08-03    413  1 days   True  False  7
```

Crete mask by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html) for test if each group contains at least one `True` - then all values of group are set to `True`s:

```
print (df.assign(diff= df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff(),
                 a = df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')),
                 a_neg = ~a,
                 s = (~a).cumsum(),
                 mask = a.groupby(s).transform('any')))

    ID      tDate  value  consec_count    diff      a  a_neg  s   mask
0   79 2019-07-12    397             1     NaT  False   True  1   True
1   79 2019-07-13    404             2  1 days   True  False  1   True
2   79 2019-07-18    405             1  5 days  False   True  2   True
3   79 2019-07-19    406             2  1 days   True  False  2   True
4   79 2019-07-20    408             3  1 days   True  False  2   True
5   79 2019-08-03    413             0 14 days  False   True  3  False
6   80 2019-06-21    397             1     NaT  False   True  4   True
7   80 2019-06-22    404             2  1 days   True  False  4   True
8   80 2019-07-18    405             1 26 days  False   True  5   True
9   80 2019-07-19    406             2  1 days   True  False  5   True
10  80 2019-07-26    408             0  7 days  False   True  6  False
11  80 2019-08-02    410             1  7 days  False   True  7   True
12  80 2019-08-03    413             2  1 days   True  False  7   True
```

Create counter per groups `s` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df.assign(diff= df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff(),
                 a = df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')),
                 a_neg = ~a,
                 s = (~a).cumsum(),
                 mask = a.groupby(s).transform('any'),
                 c = df.groupby(s).cumcount(1).add(1)))

    ID      tDate  value  consec_count    diff      a  a_neg  s   mask  c
0   79 2019-07-12    397             1     NaT  False   True  1   True  1
1   79 2019-07-13    404             2  1 days   True  False  1   True  2
2   79 2019-07-18    405             1  5 days  False   True  2   True  1
3   79 2019-07-19    406             2  1 days   True  False  2   True  2
4   79 2019-07-20    408             3  1 days   True  False  2   True  3
5   79 2019-08-03    413             0 14 days  False   True  3  False  1
6   80 2019-06-21    397             1     NaT  False   True  4   True  1
7   80 2019-06-22    404             2  1 days   True  False  4   True  2
8   80 2019-07-18    405             1 26 days  False   True  5   True  1
9   80 2019-07-19    406             2  1 days   True  False  5   True  2
10  80 2019-07-26    408             0  7 days  False   True  6  False  1
11  80 2019-08-02    410             1  7 days  False   True  7   True  1
12  80 2019-08-03    413             2  1 days   True  False  7   True  2
```

And last add `0` by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask `mask`:

```
print (df.assign(diff= df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff(),
                 a = df.groupby('ID')['tDate'].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')),
                 a_neg = ~a,
                 s = (~a).cumsum(),
                 mask = a.groupby(s).transform('any'),
                 c = df.groupby(s).cumcount(1).add(1),
                 out =  np.where(mask, df.groupby(s).cumcount(1).add(1), 0)))

    ID      tDate  value  consec_count    diff      a  a_neg  s   mask  c  out
0   79 2019-07-12    397             1     NaT  False   True  1   True  1    1
1   79 2019-07-13    404             2  1 days   True  False  1   True  2    2
2   79 2019-07-18    405             1  5 days  False   True  2   True  1    1
3   79 2019-07-19    406             2  1 days   True  False  2   True  2    2
4   79 2019-07-20    408             3  1 days   True  False  2   True  3    3
5   79 2019-08-03    413             0 14 days  False   True  3  False  1    0
6   80 2019-06-21    397             1     NaT  False   True  4   True  1    1
7   80 2019-06-22    404             2  1 days   True  False  4   True  2    2
8   80 2019-07-18    405             1 26 days  False   True  5   True  1    1
9   80 2019-07-19    406             2  1 days   True  False  5   True  2    2
10  80 2019-07-26    408             0  7 days  False   True  6  False  1    0
11  80 2019-08-02    410             1  7 days  False   True  7   True  1    1
12  80 2019-08-03    413             2  1 days   True  False  7   True  2    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This solves it!
Would you mind going into some more detail explaining the solution?  I don't follow it...

Comment: @sa_zy - For first solution?

Comment: Second solution.  I don't follow the groupby((~a).cumsum()) especially after having selected df[a], how are the ~a still there?

Comment: @sa_zy - Added explantion to answer.

Comment: there seems to be a bug with your implementation that doesn't appear in Andy L.'s solution.   I think the or-condition in a for date-diff -1 is redundant.

Comment: @sa_zy - Tested again and found my solution was not correct, also another answer return wrong output. So solution was changed, please check it.