# query to count occurances of aparticular column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with the following value

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

I need to get an out put like this, which counts each occurances of a
particular value

```
 1  1
 1  2
 1  3
 2  1
 2  2
 2  3
 3  1
 3  2 
 3  3
 1  1
 1  2
 1  3
 2  1
 2  2
 2  3
```

NB: This is a sample table Actual table is a complex table with lots of rows and columns and query contains some more conditions

Comment: Im using postgres sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count consecutive duplicates in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521725/how-to-count-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-table)

Comment: Use Tabibitosan (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523463/610979).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number repeats over different "islands" then you need to calculate a value to maintain those islands first (`grpnum`). That first step can be undertaken by subtracting a raw top-to-bottom row number (`raw_rownum`) from a partitioned row number. That result gives each "island" a reference unique to that island that can then be used to partition a subsequent row number.  As each order by can disturb the outcome I find it necessary to use individual steps and to pass the prior calculation up so it may be reused.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a854/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1  ([num] int);

INSERT INTO Table1  ([num])
VALUES  (1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    num
    , row_number() over(partition by (grpnum + num) order by raw_rownum) rn
    , grpnum + num island_num
from (
    select
           num
         , raw_rownum - row_number() over(partition by num order by raw_rownum) grpnum
         , raw_rownum
    from (
          select
              num
             , row_number() over(order by (select null)) as raw_rownum
          from table1
         ) r
     ) d
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a854/3/0)**:

```
| num | rn | island_num |
|-----|----|------------|
|   1 |  1 |          1 |
|   1 |  2 |          1 |
|   1 |  3 |          1 |
|   2 |  1 |          5 |
|   2 |  2 |          5 |
|   2 |  3 |          5 |
|   1 |  1 |          7 |
|   1 |  2 |          7 |
|   1 |  3 |          7 |
|   3 |  1 |          9 |
|   3 |  2 |          9 |
|   3 |  3 |          9 |
|   2 |  1 |         11 |
|   2 |  2 |         11 |
|   2 |  3 |         11 |
```

Comment: This is interesting and quite clever...  I had a similar idea with what you call an island, only implemented it quite differently.  One comment on PostgresQL is that I don't believe it will support `order by (select null)`.  If you change that to `order by null` or `order by (select 1)` it would take it.

Comment: @Hambone I  must admit I  wrote this in TSQL and the (select null)  is trick for that dialect but select 1 will achieve the same outcome.  Of course having access to a created timestamp or similar would be more reliable for thie ordering. I will take a look at your method which looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

`SQL Server` provide `row_number()` function :

```
select ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RN FROM <TABLE_NAME>
```

**EDIT :**

```
select * , case when (row_number() over (order by (select 1))) %3 = 0 then 3 else
           (row_number() over (order by (select 1))) %3 end [rn] from table
```

Comment: @sangeethanair ....Changing the question after you have asked it is rude. It can invalidate answers which in turn can attract downvotes

Comment: I am sorry. I didnt noticed if before.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your sample, in that you have an implied order but not an explicit one.  There is no guarantee that the database will keep and store the values the way you have them listed, so there has to be some inherent/explicit ordering mechanism to tell the database to give those values back exactly the way you listed.

For example, if you did this:

```
update test
set val = val + 2
where val < 3
```

You would find your `select *` no longer comes back the way you expected.

You indicated your actual table was huge, so I assume you have something like this you can use.  There should be something in the table to indicate the order you want...  a timestamp, perhaps, or maybe a surrogate key.

That said, assuming you have something like that and can leverage it, I believe a series of windowing functions would work.

```
with rowed as (
  select
    val,
    case
      when lag (val, 1, -1) over (order by 1) = val then 0
      else 1
    end as idx,
    row_number() over (order by 1) as rn  -- fix this once you have your order
  from
    test
),
partitioned as (
  select
    val, rn,
    sum (idx) over (order by rn) as instance
  from rowed
)
select
  val, instance, count (1) over (partition by instance order by rn)
from
  partitioned
```

This example orders by the way they are listed in the database, but you would want to change the `row_number` function to accommodate whatever your real ordering mechanism is.

```
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   1   3
2   2   1
2   2   2
2   2   3
3   3   1
3   3   2
3   3   3
1   4   1
1   4   2
1   4   3
2   5   1
2   5   2
2   5   3
```